# Pycharm -- how can I push a local project to a remote organization repo?

Tags: github, pycharm

I can push to my personal github account, but I am trying to push to an organization repo. How can I configure Pycharm to use an organization repo instead of a personal one? Thanks.

Comment: how to do you push a new project from PYCHARM to personal github account

Comment: I got the answer on how to push the project from PYCHARM to personal github account https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/manage-projects-hosted-on-github.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems not to work, I had the same problem.

This was my workaround:

1. Create a new github organization repository and name it like your local project
2. Open PyCharm and checkout the organization project into a directory different from your PyCharm project directory (if your local project with the same name lies there)
3. Close PyCharm and copy all files and folders from the checked out organization repository into your local project folder
4. Open your local project in PyCharm and add the *.idea* folder (with contains your PyCharm IDE project information) to the *.gitignore* file
5. Finally commit and push your local project content to your organization repository!
6. (Don't forget to delete the your former checkout folder)

This works because all git-paths are relative.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

1. close PyCharm
2. open a terminal in or from terminal navigate to the local project directory.
3. run your version of: `git remote add origin https://github.com/<organization>/<project>.git`
4. open PyChram and push project: "VCS"->'git'->'push'

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Goto Git > Manage Remotes
2. Add your repo remote (Organization repo)
3. Once it asks you to login with GitHub, click "Login with token"
4. Generate a GitHub token on [github.com](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and grant the permissions PyCharm tells you to but make sure you allow "org:write" too.
5. Input your generated token
6. And boom! You should be able to push to organizations